# Android convert javascript variables in webview to java variable

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

class

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
    }
}
```

onCreate()

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");    
webview.loadUrl("javascript:var elementjs = window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.getElementsByName('name')[0].src);");
```

I want to get 'elementjs' in java.

```
String element = elementjs;//like this
```

How get javascript variable in java?